# Inner div losing background when overflow on parent div after scrolling

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I have a modal which is some percentage of the screen. Within that modal are two columns. I want the entire modal to scroll together if there's overflow so I have overflow-y:auto on the parent container.

My issue is that I'm losing the background color once I scroll down on one of the opposite column.

jsfiddle that illustrates the issue clearly, just scroll on down. https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/m26nster/2/  (make sure your window is wide enough to have both columns side by side)

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner container-fluid">
    <div class="first-col col-xs-6">
      col1 data - here's the bg that's disappearing)
    </div>
    <div class="second-col col-xs-6">
      col2 data
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.first-col {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

With this setup the scroll works great, if either column has content too big I can scroll down; however, I lose the blue background on the left column below the fold if the right column causes the overflow.

I've tried messing with background-attachment to no avail. If I put overflow:auto on the columns the background works correctly but I don't want to scroll just one column, I need both columns to scroll together as in the above example.

If I remove the height attribute from first-col and it's the one causing the overflow then it also works great, but I need it to function correctly regardless of which column is causing the overflow.

How can I preserve the background color as I scroll down?

Comment: I think you want to change your `.outer { height: 100%; }` to `.outer { min-height: 100%; }` - The background is disappearing as the `height` is set to `100%`, the content overflows the container.

Comment: Did you want first-col to have full color? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/e3n5gnpo/1/

Comment: @Ronak This was almooost perfect, except the issue how is if the right column is the one causing the overflow, the left column's background does not continue down with it. How can I ensure if either column causes the overflow the background always moves down? https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/m26nster/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the entire post. You need to do these steps:

- remove col-xs-6 from both div first-col and second-col
- wrap them in another div and apply display: table to it.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.first-col {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.col-container{
   display:block;
   border-spacing: 15px;
}
.col-container .first-col,.col-container .second-col
{
display:table-cell;
padding:15px 0;
width:50%;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner container-fluid">
  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="first-col">
      col1 data - here's the bg that's disappearing)
    </div>
    <div class="second-col">
      acon ipsum dolor amet landjaeger shankle alcatra spare ribs ball tip. Pork chop kevin chicken meatball prosciutto, shoulder jerky tenderloin brisket pork belly. Pancetta picanha landjaeger strip steak burgdoggen, flank ground round sirloin. Doner salami capicola tri-tip jerky leberkas pork belly short ribs. Shoulder burgdoggen ham, pork loin landjaeger strip steak tri-tip jerky ground round pastrami pig beef. Andouille pastrami pancetta, landjaeger sirloin ball tip tail strip steak tenderloin frankfurter flank corned beef brisket. Picanha pastrami sausage, hamburger porchetta pork chop drumstick beef ribeye chicken pork loin cow meatball short ribs kielbasa. Meatloaf flank andouille alcatra prosciutto shoulder sirloin. Boudin chicken pork loin jerky cupim prosciutto. Ham meatloaf leberkas, chuck shank jowl meatball jerky beef. Flank shoulder biltong short ribs burgdoggen.
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to convert this to a table. Obviously my example was just a highly simplified case illustrating the issue I'm having, but is part of a much larger real world application in which I'm going to drastically change the modal's structure.

Comment: I am afraid your code might not be giving you what you want. You need to add another element. Let me update it with your own class name. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana Please take a look. Don't forget to vote up if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks that now fits perfectly, appreciate it